# How to count the number of points below a contour line in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I've created a heatmap in R based on simulations and plotted it using `image.plot()` and I have added contour lines by using `contour()`. I also have a data frame that contains a column for `observations in first year` and `trend size` that I have plotted on top of the heatmap using base `R` `plot`. Is there an easy way to count the number of points below the 0.5 contour line and about the 0.95 contour line?
[image]

Comment: You may want to add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are plotting a variable called `z`, you can use something like.

```
table(z>.95)
```